# Resolving a redundant link accessibility alert with a logo and "home" nav link that both go to home

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

I have a Bootstrap v5 site I'm trying to make accessible. The navbar has the company logo that links to the home page, but also a nav link "Home" that also links to the home page. WAVE evaluation tool triggers a warning for "Redundant link" since they go the same place and are next to each other.

The code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" aria-label="Main navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="/Images/company_logo.png" alt="Company logo">
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/home/about">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/home/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The obvious solutions are:

**Solution 1:** Remove the logo link. But everything I read is that it's a best practice to have your logo be a home page link.

**Solution 2:** Remove the Home link. But for accessibility I hear you should include a Home link in the navigation.

**Solution 3:** Somehow combine the logo and Home nav-item into a single link, but not sure how Bootstrap would support that especially in mobile view.

**Solution 4:** Ignore it, it's a WAVE "Alert" not a "Warning".

I'm leaning towards Solution 1; it seems to be the most accessible.

What would you do?

Comment: Would you mind adding the exact wording of the warning? Because I see an issue with your logo alt text. It’s not helpful. It’s the content of a link, and therefore should also indicate that it’s leading to Home. So you have two links leading to home, but named differently. Additionally, it’s very likely that your logo consists primarily of text, so that text should be repeated in the alt text. A Google logo would read “Google”, f.e.

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected:  [According to WebAIM though, it’s not necessary to mention Home in the logo alt text](https://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/#logos). But adding the site’s or company’s title is.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** It's pretty common to have a logo be a link to the home page.  It's fine to keep it.

**Solution 2:**  There is nothing in the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines ([WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/)) that says you must have a "Home" link in the navigation menu.  It's a pretty common thing to have but is not required.  You could remove it if you wanted to but don't do it for any accessibility reasons.  Remove it if it doesn't fit with your design, otherwise keep it.

**Solution 3:** Often there are elements between the company logo and the first menu item with the "Home" link (such as a login link or search button) so combining the links could be very messy.  There's no need to pursue this route.

**Solution 4:** Absolutely, except it's a *Warning*, not an *Alert*. You had it backwards.  WAVE is just being proactive and pointing out *usability* issues that could affect some users but it's not an *accessibility* (WCAG) failure.  It's fine to ignore this *Warning* if you're happy with your design.